# How to split a text into two parts?

Tags: php

How to split a text into two parts in PHP?
For example:

```
$text = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.';
```

How to split text into two parts so that the last character of the first part is a dot?
The result should be:

```
$part1 = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.';

$part2 = 'It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply split you text into parts using explode

```
$parts = array_filter(explode('.', $text));
```

In your case you'll have 3 items so based on your necessity you can decide which one you want to regroup together

Comment: This is not a complete answer because it does not include the code to piece together the output mentioned in the OP.

Comment: It helped me: $parts = array_filter(explode('.', $text)); $indexArrayToParts = (int)(count($parts)/2);$part1 = implode('.', array_slice($parts, 0, $indexArrayToParts)).'.';$part2 = implode('.', array_slice($parts, $indexArrayToParts));

Answer (score 1):

We can try a regex split on the pattern `(?<=\.)\s+(?!.*\..)`, which will target the second to last period in the text.

```
$text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
$parts = preg_split("/(?<=\.)\s+(?!.*\..)/", $text);
print_r($parts);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    [1] => It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
)
```

Comment: Thx, but if text is large (and has more dots) then the first part will be much larger than the second. I think the solution is: count(array_filter(explode('.', $text)))/2, this index array is the end of the first part